# HttpResponseCache doesn`t clear old files?

Tags: android, caching, httpconnection, httpresponsecache

I will soon work on a project, which uses a lot of `HTTPRequests` for mainly `JSON`s and `Images`, so I thought it is a good idea to think about caching. Basically I'm looking for a solution for

1. Start a `HTTPRequest` with a given lifetime (f.e. 3,6,12 hours)
2. Check, if that Request is available in the Cache and still valid (lifetime)
3. If Request is still valid, take it from Cache, otherwise make the Request and save its Response

I found `HttpResponseCache` class in Android. It is working, however it is **not** working like I'm expecting.

My test case is an `AsyncTask` to cache several Images. Code looks like the following:

```
URL url = new URL(link);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

Bitmap myBitmap;
try {
    connection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control","only-if-cached");

    //check if Request is in cache      
    InputStream cached = connection.getInputStream();

    //set image if in cache
    myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(cached);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    HttpURLConnection connection2 = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection2.setDoInput(true);
    connection2.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-stale=" + 60); 
    connection2.connect();

    InputStream input = connection2.getInputStream();
    myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

}

return myBitmap;

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();        
}
```

Two questions:

1. I set `max-stale=60seconds` for testing purposes. However, if I call the same URL 5minutes later, it tells me, it is loading the image from cache. **I would assume, that the image is reloaded because the HTTPRequest in the cache is out of date?** Or do I have to clean the cache myself?
2. In my `catch` block, I have to create a second `HttpURLConnection`, because I cannot add properties, after I opened an URLConnection (this happens in the connection.getInputStream()?!). Is this bad programming?

After all, I find that `HttpResponseCache` poorly documented. I came across [Volley: Fast Networking](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728), but this seems even less documented, even if it is offering exactly the things I need (Request queuing and prioritization...). **What do you use for caching?** Any links to libraries, tutorials, are welcome.

**UPDATE**
I'm not targeting Android versions lower than 4.0 (still maybe intresting for other users?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `HttpResponseCache` and `volley` are poorly documented. However, I have found that you 
can very easily extend and tweak `volley`. If you explore source code of volley, especially of:  [`CacheEntry`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/Cache.java), [`CacheDispatcher`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/CacheDispatcher.java) and [`HttpHeaderParser`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/HttpHeaderParser.java), you can see how it is implemented.

A [`CacheEntry`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/Cache.java) holds `serverDate`, `etag`, `ttl` and `sofTtl` which can represent cache state pretty well, also it has `isExpired()` and `refreshNeeded()` methods as convenience.

[`CacheDispatcher`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/CacheDispatcher.java) is implemented accurately as well:

```
// Attempt to retrieve this item from cache.
Cache.Entry entry = mCache.get(request.getCacheKey());

if (entry == null) {
    request.addMarker("cache-miss");
    // Cache miss; send off to the network dispatcher.
    mNetworkQueue.put(request);
    continue;
}

// If it is completely expired, just send it to the network.
if (entry.isExpired()) {
    request.addMarker("cache-hit-expired");
    request.setCacheEntry(entry);
    mNetworkQueue.put(request);
    continue;
}

// We have a cache hit; parse its data for delivery back to the request.
request.addMarker("cache-hit");
Response<?> response = request.parseNetworkResponse(
        new NetworkResponse(entry.data, entry.responseHeaders));
request.addMarker("cache-hit-parsed");

if (!entry.refreshNeeded()) {
    // Completely unexpired cache hit. Just deliver the response.
    mDelivery.postResponse(request, response);
} else {
    // Soft-expired cache hit. We can deliver the cached response,
    // but we need to also send the request to the network for
    // refreshing.
    request.addMarker("cache-hit-refresh-needed");
    request.setCacheEntry(entry);

    // Mark the response as intermediate.
    response.intermediate = true;

    // Post the intermediate response back to the user and have
    // the delivery then forward the request along to the network.
    mDelivery.postResponse(request, response, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                mNetworkQueue.put(request);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Not much we can do about this.
            }
        }
    });
}
```

One interesting tidbit: If cache is "soft expired", volley will deliver data from local cache immediately, and re-deliver it from server again after some time, for single request.

Finally, [`HttpHeaderParser`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/HttpHeaderParser.java) does its best to cope to server headers:

```
headerValue = headers.get("Date");
if (headerValue != null) {
    serverDate = parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
}

headerValue = headers.get("Cache-Control");
if (headerValue != null) {
    hasCacheControl = true;
    String[] tokens = headerValue.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        String token = tokens[i].trim();
        if (token.equals("no-cache") || token.equals("no-store")) {
            return null;
        } else if (token.startsWith("max-age=")) {
            try {
                maxAge = Long.parseLong(token.substring(8));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } else if (token.equals("must-revalidate") || token.equals("proxy-revalidate")) {
            maxAge = 0;
        }
    }
}

headerValue = headers.get("Expires");
if (headerValue != null) {
    serverExpires = parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
}

serverEtag = headers.get("ETag");

// Cache-Control takes precedence over an Expires header, even if both exist and Expires
// is more restrictive.
if (hasCacheControl) {
    softExpire = now + maxAge * 1000;
} else if (serverDate > 0 && serverExpires >= serverDate) {
    // Default semantic for Expire header in HTTP specification is softExpire.
    softExpire = now + (serverExpires - serverDate);
}

Cache.Entry entry = new Cache.Entry();
entry.data = response.data;
entry.etag = serverEtag;
entry.softTtl = softExpire;
entry.ttl = entry.softTtl;
entry.serverDate = serverDate;
entry.responseHeaders = headers;
```

So, ensure the server sends proper headers as well as honors etag,time-stamp and cache control headers.

Finally, you can override `getCacheEntry()` of [`Request`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/Request.java) class to return custom [`CacheEntry`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/Cache.java) make cache behave exactly according to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Soryy. But why don't you use third-party libs for this? Try to use [Volley lib](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728) for this. It maintains a cache out of the box and it is async out of the box. It works really good. Tutorials for Volley: [one (with caching demonstration)](http://captechconsulting.com/blog/clinton-teegarden/android-volley-library-tutorial), [two](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/11/android-volley-tutorial-post-download.html).

And there is another good one async, caching lib for android with good documentation - [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). Here is [Retrofit Caching Example](https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/5889518).

And [here](http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/) is their comparison.

Answer (score 1):

To enable caching, all you need to do is just install HTTP response cache at application startup by using below code:

```
File httpCacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "http");
long httpCacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
HttpResponseCache.install(httpCacheDir, httpCacheSize);
```

Whether the resource need to be fetched from network or cache, is taken care by `HttpResponseCache`. The age of cache is specified in the response headers of the resource request. For example this [image](https://developer.android.com/images/brand/en_generic_rgb_wo_45.png), specifies cache age of 43200 seconds.

You can verify whether the resource is fetched from cache or network, by using following apis:

- [getHitCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html#getHitCount%28%29) : Number of Http requests which were served by cache.
- [getNetworkCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html#getNetworkCount%28%29) : Number of Http requests which were served by network.

Regarding `max-stale`, you have misunderstood it's purpose. It is used to permit stale cache responses. Here is it's definition from the [rfc documentation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3) :

> Indicates that the client is willing to accept a response that has
>   exceeded its expiration time. If max-stale is assigned a value, then
>   the client is willing to accept a response that has exceeded its
>   expiration time by no more than the specified number of seconds. If no
>   value is assigned to max-stale, then the client is willing to accept a
>   stale response of any age.

Regarding cache control directive `only-if-cached`, only use it when you need to show something while your application is downloading latest content. So the question of handling new `HttpUrlConnection` in exception handler does not arise. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html):

> Sometimes you'll want to show resources if they are available
>   immediately, but not otherwise. This can be used so your application
>   can show something while waiting for the latest data to be downloaded.
>   To restrict a request to locally-cached resources, add the
>   only-if-cached directive

One suggestion, add `finally` block, where you release the connection by calling [disconnect](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#disconnect%28%29).